# Difference in creating indexes in mongo db

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-indexes

I would like to know if there is a difference between these two types of index

My goal is to create a composite index in the search for these two keys

```
   collection.Indexes.CreateOne(
        new CreateIndexModel<Data>(
            Builders<Data>.IndexKeys.Combine(
            Builders<Data>.IndexKeys.Ascending(a => a.Id),
            Builders<Data>.IndexKeys.Ascending(a => a.Name))));
 
  
    collection.Indexes.CreateOne(
        new CreateIndexModel<Data>(
            Builders<Data>
                .IndexKeys
                .Ascending(a => a.Id)
                .Descending(a => a.Name)));
```

In tests they apparently created the same index, I was unable to identify any difference using Find().Explain()

Answer (score -1):

Here is how the two types of indices you've provided are meant to function:

1. The first one is an **ascending** composite index on fields `Id` and `Name`.
   This index would be useful for queries that filter first on `Id` (in **ascending** order) and then on `Name` (also in **ascending** order).
2. The second one is a composite index on field `Id` in **ascending** order, and `Name` in **descending** order. This index would be useful for queries that filter first on `Id` (in ascending order) and then on `Name` (in descending order).

Even though these indices might appear similar, they are utilized maximally in different querying circumstances based on the direction (ascending or descending) specified for the fields.

If you try to use `Find().Explain()` and are not noticing any difference in output, it could be because your test dataset isn't large enough, the fields `Id` and `Name` might not have enough unique entries to create a observable difference or your queries aren't tailored in a way to best utilize the order distinctions in these indices.

Comment: This looks like LLM-generated

Comment: If this is LLM-generated it is one of the rare occasions where it is actually correct.

Comment: In addition to the direction in the query, asc or desc, the way the indexes are constructed is different. Does this difference in construction between them imply a difference in execution?